# Select with oledb

Tags: c#, for-loop, oledb

I Can't do select... 
I can not do a select inside a go with dates
recebe uma variavel que determina quantidade de meses a ser calculada MesesDemanda
Calculated a date before and one after

```
for (int i = 1; i <= MesesDemanda; i++)
            {
                int cont = 0;
                DateTime dataposterior = DateTime.Now, dataanterior = DateTime.Now;
                dataanterior = dataanterior.AddMonths(i);
                dataposterior = dataposterior.AddMonths(-(i - 1));
                con.Open();
                cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT HistSaida.dataHistSaida, HistSaida.idProdutoHistSaida, HistSaida.qtdHistSaida FROM HistSaida WHERE (((HistSaida.dataHistSaida) BETWEEN #" + dataanterior + "# AND #" + dataposterior + "#) AND idProdutoHistSaida = " + idProduto + ")", con);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Demanda = Demanda + Convert.ToInt32(dr["qtdHistSaida"]);
                        cont = 1;
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
                Valordivisao = Valordivisao + cont;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameters like below

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT dataHistSaida, idProdutoHistSaida, qtdHistSaida FROM HistSaida WHERE ((dataHistSaida <=?  AND dataHistSaida >= ?) AND idProdutoHistSaida = ?)", con);
```

now you can set values like below

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dataanterior );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dataposterior );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", idProduto );
```

if you need to take Sum of `qtdHistSaida` column then you can change the sql statement as below

```
SELECT SUM(qtdHistSaida) FROM HistSaida WHERE ((dataHistSaida <=?  AND dataHistSaida >= ?) AND idProdutoHistSaida = ?)
```

now you can use `ExecuteScalar` method to get the sum value as below

```
var result  = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: and more variable cont?

Comment: I need more Help, I cant do the select

Comment: in database what are the data types you given for dataHistSaida  and idProdutoHistSaida columns

Comment: dataHistSaida is date and idProdutoHistSaida is integer